# EntityFramework Error about Different Contexts. Looks like the same context to me

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm tryng to run the following LINQ query and getting the indicated error:

```
var x = (from o in _dataService.Outputs join ov in _dataService.OperandValues on o.OutputID equals ov.OutputID select o).ToList();
```

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are
> associated with different contexts.

I understand that I cannot use two different contexts in the same query, but I'm failing to see how this LINQ query is using multiple contexts.  Two different tables in the same context, sure.  But I don't understand why I'm getting this error.  I would appreciate any insights you have to offer.

Thank you.

Content of the Output class:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Dematic.Tools.QMA.DataAccess.QMA
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Output: QmaEntityBase
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Output()
        {
            this.OperandValues = new HashSet<OperandValue>();
            this.OutputXBrands = new HashSet<OutputXBrand>();
            this.OutputCountries = new HashSet<OutputCountry>();
            this.HistoryOperandValues = new HashSet<HistoryOperandValue>();
            this.HistoryOutputs = new HashSet<HistoryOutput>();
            this.ScenarioOptions = new HashSet<ScenarioOption>();
        }

        public System.Guid OutputID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public System.Guid RuleSetID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> OriginalOutputID { get; set; }
        public System.Guid ServiceCatalogID { get; set; }
        public System.Guid QuotingOfficeID { get; set; }
        public System.Guid StatusID { get; set; }
        public int RecipeID { get; set; }
        public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }
        public bool IsSyncedToOwner { get; set; }
        public System.Guid CalculationMethodID { get; set; }
        public System.Guid CalculationLevelID { get; set; }
        public string ToolTip { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsCtsControlled { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string SourceApplication { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDateTime { get; set; }
        public string CreateUser { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifyDateTime { get; set; }
        public string ModifyUser { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> LaborLevelID { get; set; }
        public System.Guid WBSID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> BridgingClassificationTypeID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> TradeDisciplineClassificationTypeID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ProjectTimelineTypeID { get; set; }
        public System.Guid AttributeID { get; set; }
        public string PopulatedRecipe { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> OutputCurrencyID { get; set; }

        public virtual WBS WBS { get; set; }
        public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
        public virtual BridgingClassificationType BridgingClassificationType { get; set; }
        public virtual CalculationLevel CalculationLevel { get; set; }
        public virtual CalculationMethod CalculationMethod { get; set; }
        public virtual LaborLevel LaborLevel { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<OperandValue> OperandValues { get; set; }
        public virtual Output ParentOutput { get; set; }
        public virtual ProjectTimelineType ProjectTimelineType { get; set; }
        public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
        public virtual RuleSet RuleSet { get; set; }
        public virtual ServiceCatalog ServiceCatalog { get; set; }
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
        public virtual TradeDisciplineClassificationType TradeDisciplineClassificationType { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<OutputXBrand> OutputXBrands { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<OutputCountry> OutputCountries { get; set; }
        public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<HistoryOperandValue> HistoryOperandValues { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<HistoryOutput> HistoryOutputs { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ScenarioOption> ScenarioOptions { get; set; }
        public virtual CurrencyType CurrencyType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Content of the OperandValue class:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Dematic.Tools.QMA.DataAccess.QMA
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class OperandValue : QmaEntityBase
    {
        public System.Guid OperandValueID { get; set; }
        public System.Guid OutputID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> AttributeID { get; set; }
        public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string Tag1 { get; set; }
        public string Tag2 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> NumericValue { get; set; }
        public string TextValue { get; set; }
        public string SourceApplication { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDateTime { get; set; }
        public string CreateUser { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifyDateTime { get; set; }
        public string ModifyUser { get; set; }
        public decimal InternalValue { get; set; }

        public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
        public virtual Output Output { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of `_dataService`? Specifically `Outputs` and `OperandValues`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for.  Do you want the content of the .edmx file related to those two tables?

Comment: @MattU - I added the auto-generated class definitions that live within the data model.  If there is something else that you wanted to see, let me know.

Comment: Okay so `_dataService` is your database context? This is strange indeed. Is that the only LINQ query you're executing, or are you doing more database operations around it as well?

Comment: (Someone else wrote the application.  I'm just trying to add a new feature.)  This is the only LINQ query that is being executed in this method.  When the user clicks a button, I want to populate a data grid with the results of this query.  So it's the only query being run at this time.

Comment: How / where is `_dataService` defined?

Comment: `_dataService` is an instance of `IDataService` which is passed into the constructor of the view model that I'm working with.  `IDataService` is too large to post here, but the `Outputs` property is defined as `IQueryable<Output>` and the `OperandValues` property is `IQueryable<OperandValue>`.  They are both read-only (getter is defined, but not setter.)

Comment: Is it possible that the implementation of `IDataService` is using a different database context for `Outputs` and `OperandValues`? Sounds like something like that is happening behind the scenes somewhere.

Comment: Ah Ha!   Thank you @MattU.  So the DataService implementation is using a "UnitOfWork" object to return these members.  `UnitOfWork` implements IDisposable and is being called through `using` statements.  So when you dig deep enough, we are getting two different units of work using different contexts (because each unit of work is opening a new connection.)  This Unit of Work concept appears to be in use in order to transactionalize the data access... but I guess it's getting in my way for this.  But now that I know where the problem is coming from, I can try to figure out how to overcome it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments on the original question, two different database contexts are indeed being used in the underlying `IDataService` implementation, related to a `UnitOfWork` object. To resolve the error, you'll need to figure out how to use a shared database context.